# how to get one order for each item in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I wants to receive one order for each item(of an order).
For example:
If we get a order of three items then admin->WooCommerce->Orders will show three different orders for each item.

Any idea?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in your child theme function.php. I hope this code will you to achieve your goal.

Note : I would suggest please use this code in your local setup first.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );  

function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {

    global $wp,$wpdb;

    if(!empty($wp->query_vars['order-received'])){

        $order = new WC_Order($wp->query_vars['order-received']);
    
        $arrayCount = array();

        $productIDArray = array();

        $productQtyArray = array();

        foreach($order->get_items() as $originalOrderItem){

                createNewOrderAndRecordPayment($wp->query_vars['order-

received'],$originalOrderItem['item_meta']['_product_id']

[0],$originalOrderItem['item_meta']['_qty'][0]);

        }       

        wp_redirect( '/thank-you/' );

        exit;
    }
}

function createNewOrderAndRecordPayment($orderID,$productID,$qty) {

    global $wpdb;

    global $woocommerce;

    $original_order_id = $orderID;

    $original_order = new WC_Order($original_order_id);

    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

    $order_data =  array(

        'post_type'     => 'shop_order',

        'post_status'   => 'publish',

        'ping_status'   => 'closed',

        'post_author'   => $currentUser->ID, 

        'post_excerpt' => $original_order->customer_message, 

        'post_password' => uniqid( 'order_' )   // Protects the post just in case

    );

    $order_id = wp_insert_post( $order_data, true );

    if ( is_wp_error( $order_id ) ){

        $msg = "Unable to create order:" . $order_id->get_error_message();;

        throw new Exception( $msg );

    } else {

        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_shipping', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_order_shipping', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_ip_value', get_client_ip());

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_discount', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_order_discount', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cart_discount', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_cart_discount', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_tax', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_order_tax', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_shipping_tax', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_order_shipping_tax', true) );

        if($orderLoop == 1){

            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_total', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_order_total', true) );

        }

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_key',  'wc_' . 

apply_filters('woocommerce_generate_order_key', uniqid('order_') ) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_customer_user', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_currency', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_order_currency', true) );

        if($orderLoop == 1){

            update_post_meta( $order_id,

 '_prices_include_tax',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_prices_include_tax', true) );

        }

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_customer_ip_address',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_customer_ip_address', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_customer_user_agent',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_customer_user_agent', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_city', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_city', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_state',  

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_state', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_postcode', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_postcode', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_email', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_phone',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_phone', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_address_1',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_address_1', 

true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_address_2',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_address_2',

 true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_country',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_country',

 true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_first_name',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_billing_first_name', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_last_name',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_last_name', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_billing_company',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_billing_company', 

true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_country',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_shipping_country', 

true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_first_name',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_shipping_first_name', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_last_name',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_shipping_last_name', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_company',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_shipping_company',

 true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id,

 '_shipping_address_1',get_post_meta($original_order_id,

 '_shipping_address_1', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_address_2',get_post_meta($original_order_id, 

'_shipping_address_2', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_city', 

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_shipping_city', true));

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_state',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_shipping_state', 

true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 

'_shipping_postcode',get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_shipping_postcode', 

true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_delivery_date',$deliveryDate);

        $itemName = get_the_title($productID);

        $quantity = $qty;

        $lineTotal = $originalOrderItem['line_total'];

        $lineTax = $originalOrderItem['line_tax'];

        $productID = $productID; 

        $item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array(

            'order_item_name'       => $itemName,

            'order_item_type'       => 'line_item'

        ) );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_qty', $quantity );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', $productID );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal', 

wc_format_decimal( $lineTotal ) );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', wc_format_decimal( 

$lineTotal ) );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_tax', wc_format_decimal( '0' ) );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal_tax', 

wc_format_decimal( '0' ) );

        $original_order_shipping_items = 

$original_order->get_items('shipping');

        foreach ( $original_order_shipping_items as 

$original_order_shipping_item ) {

            $ShippingItemID = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array(

                'order_item_name'       => 

$original_order_shipping_item['name'],

                'order_item_type'       => 'shipping'

            ) );

            if ( $ShippingItemID ) {

                wc_add_order_item_meta( $ShippingItemID, 'method_id', 

$original_order_shipping_item['method_id'] );

                wc_add_order_item_meta( $ShippingItemID, 'cost', 

wc_format_decimal( $original_order_shipping_item['cost'] ) );

            }

        }

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_method', 

        get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_payment_method', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_method_title',   

get_post_meta($original_order_id, '_payment_method_title', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order->id, 'Transaction ID',     

    get_post_meta($original_order_id, 'Transaction ID', true) );

        $order->payment_complete();

        $order->update_status('processing');
    }

    return $order_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am receiving following error-
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_client_ip() in functions.php on line 93